# systemverilog - how multiple increment operators in a is a single statement work

Tags: system-verilog

Would the increment happen Left to right or right to left in the following case:

```
desc.src_addr = {rdata[i++],rdata[i++],rdata[i++],rdata[i++],rdata[i++],rdata[i++],rdata[i++],rdata[i++]};
```

Assuming `i = 0` at the start of the above statement, would the end resolution be which of the two below:

```
desc.src_addr = {rdata[0],rdata[1],rdata[2],rdata[3],rdata[4],rdata[5],rdata[6],rdata[7]};
desc.src_addr = {rdata[7],rdata[6],rdata[5],rdata[4],rdata[3],rdata[2],rdata[1],rdata[0]};
```

Is there anything in LRM that talks about this?

Obviously, my aim is to avoid hardcoding the indices in the above statement to avoid typo and oversight issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be good to know what the SystemVerilog LRM says when writing SystemVerilog code. Do you have a [copy](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html)?
See section *11.4.2 Increment and decrement operators* and look for the word **undefined**.

A much better way of writing this code would be using the streaming operator, section *11.4.14 Streaming operators (pack/unpack)*

```
desc.src_addr = {<<{rdata}}; //reverses bit order
```